# Tailwind Padding not working same for input and label

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am designing a form using tailwind and this is one of the element of it.

```
<label class="bg-gray-500 rounded rounded-r-none p-2">#</label>
<input type="text" class="rounded rounded-l-none focus:outline-none p-2 -ml-2">
```

[image]

and it shows like this, as you can see i have added p-2 to both so ideally i want both height to be same, but obviously that's not the case because input brings some default height. so how do i make both of them same height ?

Comment: to some developers, this post can be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66484296/some-tailwind-styles-not-working-in-production-with-next-js/76828148#76828148

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can wrap your code inside a flex container. I have removed the margin-left class so that it looks better.

```css
/* For presentation */

body {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #E2E8F0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/1.8.10/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="flex"> <!-- Wrapped inside flex container -->
  <label class="bg-gray-500 rounded rounded-r-none p-2">#</label>
  <input type="text" class="rounded rounded-l-none focus:outline-none p-2" placeholder="Same Height">
</div>
```

Comment: hain ? why did not i think of that. :D lol brilliant. Thanks.