# Some Tailwind styles not working in production with Next.js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

For some reason a few styles don't seem to be working in production build hosted on Netlify. This seems to only be happening on a single component. It's a wrapper located at `./layout/FormLayout.tsx` (don't know if that changes anything). Here is the wrapper:

```js
const FormLayout: React.FC<FormLayout> = ({ children, title, description }) => {
    return (
        <div className="w-screen mt-32 flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
            <div className="p-6 flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
                <h2 className="text-4xl font-semibold text-blue-400">
                    {title}
                </h2>
                {description && (
                    <h6 className="mt-4 text-md font-medium">{description}</h6>
                )}
                <div className="mt-12 w-max">{children}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

and it's used here:

```js
const Register: React.FC<RegisterProps> = () => {
    return (
        <FormLayout title="Register" description="Register with your email.">
            {/* form stuff. styles do work in here */}
        </FormLayout>
    )
}
```

Here are some of the config files:

tailwind config:

```js
module.exports = {
    purge: ['./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}', './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
    darkMode: 'class',
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    variants: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
}
```

postcss config:

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

Here is a graphical example of what is happening:

[image]

[image]

For my build command, I use `next build && next export`, and Netlify deploys the `/out` directory.

All the code is [here via github](https://github.com/herbievine/alpine-web)

Comment: for some of you, add `important: true` in `tailwind.config.js` before `content:[]` with in the brackets `{}` and it should work fine.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

For anyone seeing this in the future, just add the path to any new folder in the `purge` array into the tailwind config like this:

```js
module.exports = {
    purge: [
        "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
        // Add more here
    ],
    darkMode: 'class',
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    variants: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
}
```

#### December 2021 Update:

After TailwindCSS v.3, the config file is slightly different. The above configuration would be:

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    // Add extra paths here
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

#### NextJS App Directory

TailwindCSS is fully supported in NextJS 13, you simply need to add it as a dependency.

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    // using ./src/ dir
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    // using ./ dir
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    // add more paths here
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: Thanks, default config had darkMode: false, changed it to 'class' and my classNames started working.

Comment: Well just so you know, changing it to class means that if there's an element with a class of `dark`, each child can use Tailwind's `dark:` prefix.

Comment: Oh I forgot to add /layouts/ in the purge array. It was driving me crazy, thank you very much!

Comment: This is awesome! I was scratching my head for a couple of days, why this was not working. Strange that this was working perfectly in dev but not on prod. Thanks :)

Comment: @JeremyRajan it's because this config is only used when compiling for production. It's used to discover which classes should be saved from tree-shaking. More info is [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production).

Comment: You're the best

Comment: After spending 3 hours trying to figure out what was wrong, this finally solved it for me. Thanks!

Comment: `"./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",` worked for me

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue.

I changed these :

```
purge: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
```

to these :

```
purge: ["./pages/**/*.js", "./components/**/*.js"],
```

and that's it. problem solved!
weird issue

Comment: `"./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",` was such a clutch suggestion

Comment: separating extensions solved the issue ```["./components/**/*.ts", "./components/**/*.tsx"]```

Answer (score 6):

In my case, it was a `directory` not being listed in the `content` property of `tailwind.config.js` file. so any component residing in that directory was not being checked by tailwind.

My new component was in a folder called `providers`, and it was not listed in `content`.

so after changing `content` list to:

```
 content: [
     // ...
     "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
     "./providers/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",  // the key was this line
 ]
```

The `providers` directory was also being checked by tailwind.
So any directory which consists of a component that uses tailwind utility classes must be included in this list.

Answer (score 1):

in my case this was happening because i wasn't using the correct address in `purge` in `tailwind.config.css`

Answer (score 1):

For those upgrading to NextJs v13, make sure to update `tailwind.config.js` adding the `app` directory like this:

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is having issues with not updating dom changes accordingly.
Check if imports and filenames are written with the same case!

Header.js != header.js

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me sporadically and I eventually found that if the only change I made to my site since the last deploy was to responsive attributes, e.g. changing `md:w-1/4` to `sm:w-1/4` then the deployed site would be missing the class corresponding to `sm:w-1/4`. Adding any new path (even a fictitious one) to the `purge: [...` array and redeploying solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This one was killing me - it turned out to be the order of the string

This works `{js,ts,jsx,tsx}` this does not `{ts,tsx,js,jsx}`

Extract from tailwind.config.js below:

```
export const content = [
  "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
];
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to use the useEffect() and "import tw-elements" (in file _app.js):

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import Layout from "../components/Layout"

import "../styles/globals.css"

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {

    useEffect(() => {
        import('tw-elements');
    }, []);

    return (
        <Layout className="scroll-smooth transition-all">
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>

    )
}

export default MyApp
```