# The Next.js app does not work well after creating the image

Tags: node.js, docker, next.js, dockerfile, tailwind-css

I have a problem after creating a docker image.

If I build applications without Docker (npm run build, npm start), everything works correctly. Screenshots below.

Please suggest how to fix the problem

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat

RUN mkdir /brahhouse

WORKDIR /brahhouse

COPY ./package*.json /brahhouse

RUN npm install

COPY . /brahhouse

RUN npm run build

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I build docker image with command:

`docker build -t brahouse .`

I run docker image with command:

`docker run -p 3000:3000 brahouse`

Screenshots:

App without Docker

[image]

App in Docker Images

[image]

Comment: How exactly does it not work? What does your docker run command look like? What does the part of your app that listens on a port look like?

Comment: Are you using TailwindCSS? Most probably your CSS is being purged due to production mode. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66484297/11613622

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved**

Thank you **brc-dd**

**Solution:**

Editing tailwind.config.js (purge -> content) Set the correct paths for components, pages and other folders used by tailwind-css